# Error when trying to process Wikipedia data

Tags: jquery

I came this guideline:

http://www.bauer-power.net/2010/09/use-jquery-to-add-wikipedia-content-to.html#.VF9d2fmsUoo

And when testing it out as is I get the following error to my console log and nothing is displayed: 
SyntaxError: missing name after . operator

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Here is my complete code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
action=parse&page=google&prop=text&format=json&callback=?', function(json) { 
$('#wiki').html(json.parse.text.*);
$("#wiki").find("a:not(.references a)").attr("href", function(){ return"
http://www.wikipedia.org" + $(this).attr("href");}); 
$("#wiki").find("a").attr("target", "_blank"); 
});


});
</script>
</head>  
<body>
<div id="wiki">&nbsp;</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you get a line number for that error message? My guess is that it is somewhere around here: `json.parse.text.*`. `*` is a multiplication operator, and you seem to us it like a propery name. Why it was written that way in that tutorial, I don't know, but the comments underneath the tutorial also complain about this syntax error, so maybe the tutorial is just not good. :)

Comment: @goleztrol yes it was related to json.parse.text.*, how should this be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json.parse.text.*` is a syntax error. `*` is an operator, and you need an identifier. If you use bracket notation, it should work: `json.parse.text['*']`.

Also, you have strings split across lines that you should fix:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=google&prop=text&format=json&callback=?', function(json) { 
$('#wiki').html(json.parse.text['*']);
$("#wiki").find("a:not(.references a)").attr("href", function(){ return "http://www.wikipedia.org" + $(this).attr("href");}); 
$("#wiki").find("a").attr("target", "_blank"); 
});


});
</script>
</head>  
<body>
<div id="wiki">&nbsp;</div>

</body>
</html>
```